# SQL JOIN two tables with two equally named columns

Tags: sql, join

I have two tables that I'd like to join

Right now I just do :

```
SELECT * FROM (default_insurance) 
JOIN default_profiles ON uid = default_profiles.id 
WHERE `uid` = '1
```

problem is that both `default_insurance` and `default_profiles` contains a column named `company`, and I only want the one from `default_insurance`, but is there a way to make a join that will automatically prefer columns from one of the tables WITHOUT having to SELECT (all columns that I want)

Comment: No - and btw: it's a recommended best practice to **always** explicitly spell out the columns you want. **DON'T USE** `SELECT *` in your production code!

Comment: You should tell use what RDBMS you are using.

Comment: Deleted my answer as I didn't read your whole scenario thoroughly. `NATURAL JOIN` won't help with that as it would join on the basis of the common name.

Comment: @marc_s why not use it in production, what should i write instead to make it more efficient?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can always specify what exactly do you need (+use table aliases):

```
SELECT t1.*, t2.company AS default_insurance_company
FROM default_profiles t1 LEFT JOIN default_insurance t2
ON t1.uid = t2.id
WHERE t1.uid = 1
```

(MySQL example)

Above will return all columns from t1 and additionally column `company` from t2, but on your result it will be named `default_insurance_company`.

Answer (score 1):

Automatically no. You need to use like this:

```
SELECT [all columns that you want], di.company
FROM default_insurance di
JOIN default_profiles dp ON di.uid = dp.id 
WHERE di.uid = '1
```